# WFFM Error Message: "This action cannot be added. Your configuration does not support it"

Tags: wffm

I have tried but when I add custom action to Save actions to a WFFM (9.0) form in Sitecore 9.1 I get a pop up saying "This action cannot be added. Your configuration does not support it."

There is some configuration issue. But I am not sure what configuration is required here.

Need help

## Created class for custom submit action

[image: created class for custom submit action]

## Linking custom action with created custom class

[image: linking custom action with created custom class]

## Error message when tried to add custom submit action

[image: Error message when tried to add custom submit action]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WFFM is deprecated in Sitecore 9.1

You can also see following note on https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Web_Forms_For_Marketers.aspx page's banner

"Note! Web Forms For Marketers was deprecated with the release of Sitecore XP 9.1"

Comment: what about sitecore 9.0 ?

Comment: WFFM supports on 9.0

Answer (score 1):

WFFM is not supported in Sitecore 9.1

This excerpt is taken from the [9.1 Upgrade guide](https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/E78AB08CE53F4C27B668A6D49791C9D3.ashx):

> **Web Forms for Marketers**
>   SitecoreXP 9.1.0 does not support the Web
>   Forms for Marketers module. If you are using the Web Forms for
>   Marketers module, you must disable it before you upgrade to Sitecore
>   XP 9.1.0.